# How to turn SCD type 4 into type 6

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, scd

I am working with a data model (in a data mart) that has a type 4 slowly-changing dimension. The implementation is unlike what I typically see.  The model looks like:

[image]

(If not clear, the issue is that DimProductHistory is not part of the fact table's composite key.  Alternatively, DimProduct is not snowflaked off of DimProduct.)

In a BI tool (e.g., Power BI), my users want the option to slice by the current product attributes or by the historical product attributes.  For example, they want the ability to see measure Total Sales sliced by Current Product Color and by Historical Product Color.  How can I achieve this?  My thought process right now is to transform the model so that product becomes a type 6 dimension table.  But, this seems like the incorrect solution.  (Why fight it being type 4?)

If it helps, I have the following table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactSales(
    DateKey bigint
    , ProductKey bigint
    , SaleAmount decimal(10,2)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.DimProduct(
    ProductKey bigint
    , Color varchar(15)
    , Size varchar(3)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.DimProductHistory(
    ProductHistoryKey bigint
    , ProductKey bigint
    , RowCurrentFlag bit
    , RowStartDate datetime
    , RowEndDate datetime
    , Color varchar(15)
    , Size varchar(3)
)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I initially tried that, but I couldn't figure out how to format it properly.

Comment: The editor itself explains how, but a quick google on putting tabular data in stackoverflow will find it, as will editing another question which already has tabular data.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support